# remove "resourse id #--" from image name

Tags: php, image, curl

when I am displaying(PHP echo) an image name from the server,it's shows like,

Resource id #32global_2012062513406170744fe83172d6c99.jpg
Resource id #33330394727_2012062613406707734fe90335d0a5e.jpg

How can I remove "Resource id #32" associated with image name? then only I can display the image from the server? Or there is any other way to display images?
code is

```
 69 if(is_dir($dir))
 70         {               
 71         $dir = opendir($dir);   
 72                 while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
 73                 {       
 74                         if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
 75                         {
 76                                 $files[] = $file;
 77                         }
 78                 }
 79         closedir($dir);
 80         }
 81 //srand ((double) microtime( )*1000000);
 82 $randnum = mt_rand(0,(sizeof($files)-1));
 83 $img = $dir.$files[$randnum];
 84 echo $img;
```

Thanks!

Comment: It'd help if you'd show what code you were using...

Comment: "Resource ID" thing appears when you try to output a variable that is not supposed to be outputted directly (sometimes it is meaningful to do so, but not in most production cases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(is_dir($dir))
{               
    $openDir = opendir($dir);   
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($openDir)))
    {       
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
        {
            $files[] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($openDir);
}
//srand ((double) microtime( )*1000000);
$randnum = mt_rand(0,(sizeof($files)-1));
$img = $dir.$files[$randnum];
echo $img;
```

use this.